# classic asp .net 2.0 web application Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: asp.net, iis, viewstate

I'm having some problems running a web application in IIS7.

I get the following error on specific pages!
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

I'm not running on a web farm as the application is just running on my local iis.
I have tried all the comments from: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218

I have also tried to set :

But none of these seem to have solved the issue!
Help on this is greatly appreciated as I have yet to discover why this is not working.
It's only this 1 classic asp .net 2.0 web application that is producing this problem.

Comment: check http://codeverge.com/asp.net.state-management/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-t/306199

Comment: Thanks, but that post does not seem to be the issue.
Firstly the page in which the issue arises does not have any of the mentioned controls(Gridview, Detailview, Formview). Also I am waiting for the page to fully load before performing any other actions.